# "Angry with" vs. "angry at" vs. "angry on"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-with

Which is the most appropriate/correct usage?

> - Are you angry on me?
> - Are you angry with me?
> - Are you angry at me?

Comment: I've never heard "angry on me" before.

Comment: Nor I; it seems rare [according to ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angry+about%2Cangry+to%2Cangry+for%2Cangry+on&year_start=1600&year_end=2770&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and except for a brief rise in usage ca. 1780, is less commonly used than angry about, to, or for.

Comment: I am a South-Indian and I was recently confused about this usage - "angry on" vs "angry with" vs "angry at" someone. I understand that "angry with" someone is the correct usage. However I realized that "angry on someone" is a direct translation from Tamil, a South Indian language.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have never heard the phrase "**angry on**" used before.

Regarding the other two, I would say that it depends upon the context.

If directed at a person "**angry with**" should always be used.

> e.g. I was very angry with her.

If directed at a situation I believe "**angry at**" would also be acceptable.

> e.g. I was very angry at how rainy it was.

The key is who the anger is aimed at. "**Angry at**" is not really aimed at anyone.

So in the example you give, "**Are you angry with me?**" is correct.

Not sure how much use Google NGrams is here. It does at least show that "angry on" is used very rarely:

[image]

Comment: It could even be angry on is a literal translation from, for example, Dutch. "Boos zijn op" lit. "being angry on".

Comment: I'm surprised "angry at" got so many hits. If my anger is directed towards something other than a person, I'd say "angry about" or "angry that."

Comment: [This NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=angry+at+him%2Cangry+with+him&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) suggests *angry at [someone]* has gained currency is US usage over recent decades (there's no such increase on the British side). I can't help feeling this is down to conflation with *mad at [someone]*, as noted in @Andrew Vit's answer.

Comment: One of my asian friends uses "angry on" quite frequently, which I always thought was totally weird. Thanks for such a detailed answer. I am changing my acceptance to your answer.

Comment: Almost all the dictionaries say that you can say either angry with a person or angry at a person, though the use of with is more common and idiomatic. According to Collins, the use of at was formerly considered to be incorrect, but it's acceptable now.

Comment: I grew up only having ever heard "angry at",  and is only recently that I started hearing "angry with" all the time. Very interesting

Answer (score 8):

The second one:

> Are you angry with me?

is correct. Curiously, we also say *"are you mad at me?"* which can cause some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Both **angry at** and **angry with** are correct. But 'angry on' is incorrect.

**angry at/with somebody** -

Are you angry with me? Are you angry at me?

*References*-

angry **with** (sometimes **at**) a person - Basic English Usage by Michael Swan

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/angry -

He's really angry **at/with** me

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/angry

- angry **with/at** somebody

Please don't be angry with me.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/angry -

My parents were very angry **with** me.

You can say that someone is angry **at** someone

Please don’t get angry **at** me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTEailc5QSI -

Don't get angry **with** him. (Don't get angry **at** him)

Comment: If you can provide reliable sources that support “*angry* **with / at someone** ” it's an upvote from me. Great answers should either provide detailed explanations or references

Comment: angry with (sometimes at) a person - Basic English Usage by Michael Swan/// He's really angry at/with me... - Cambridge dictionary/// angry with/at somebody- Oxford Learner's Dictionaries/// You can say that someone is angry at someone- Please don’t get angry at me. - Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

Comment: I should have said, the references (preferably with links) should go in the answer, not in the comments. Adding the dictionary links should be easy enough. 