# "To be mad at somebody" vs. "to be mad with somebody"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-with

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Angry with” vs. “angry at” vs. “angry on”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43671/angry-with-vs-angry-at-vs-angry-on)

Can the preposition *at* in the following sentence be replaced by *with*?

> I'm mad at you.

In my mother tongue we say that we are mad *with* someone, not *at*.

Comment: Off topic: when we fix the formatting/title/spelling/punctuation/tags in your post, please take note and format your future posts accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I will take it in my future posts :D

Comment: Mad is a hard word anyway, since it has different meanings in British English and American English.

Comment: It has both senses in American English, but it's most likely to mean _angry_ unless it comes with a polar adverb like _absolutely_. In the _angry_ sense, it uses _at_ for the person and _about_ for the reason. _Mad with_, on the other hand, can only be used for the reason, and the meaning is _insane_, not _angry_. _Mad with desire_ is fine, but not _*mad with Bill_.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. In British English "mad with somebody" is just fine.

Comment: The cited question is NOT a duplicate of this one. This question asks about use of the word "mad". The supposed duplicate asks about use of the word "angry". Just because they have similar meanings doesn't mean they are used the same way in a sentence -- and in this case they most definitely are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English you are "mad at" a person, institution, etc. You wouldn't say you are "mad with" them.

Inconsistently, you are "angry with" a person, not "angry at" them.